# Android cache db stored image bitmaps

Tags: android, libraries

I'm developing an app which uses the local sqlite database to load images to the app, images are high resolution, so it consumes lots of memory, also not releasing the memory.
Are there any good android libraries to cache local stored images, or can can any one suggest me a good method to handle these images...

Comment: stored the imagepath in db because image stored in db is the bad concept

Comment: no, requirement was app to work in offline mode too... so had no choice..

Comment: any update on this thread?

Answer (score 0):

I have to work with large bitmaps once and the only library that worked [android-query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/). You may have to read files from your DB to internal or external storage first to take full advantage of the library. See their [image loading docs](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading).

Answer (score 0):

these links can help you :-

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

http://denniskubes.com/2012/11/16/android-image-downloading-and-caching/

i am using lazylist for same problem !!